# ProfilePictureSample is not present in facebook sdk

Tags: android

I have downloaded the Facebook SDK from https://developers.facebook.com .It mentioned about 
the sample ProfilePictureSample But I am not seeing this sample.Can anybody help me out .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not presesent in SDK, you could use this https://github.com/imkevinxu/totoro/tree/master/facebook-android-sdk-3.0/samples/ProfilePictureSample